# How to correctly import missing values from SPSS portable files?

Tags: r, import, spss, na

As mentioned in other questions, the best way to import a SPSS dataset into R, is to first export the SPSS file to "portable SPSS" format, and then use memisc as follows:

```
library(memisc) 
mydata <- as.data.set(spss.portable.file("myspss.por"))
```

But my problem is that NAs are encoded as text (even that I specified the NA values in SPSS)

My solution is to do this for each variable:

```
mydata$v1[mydata$v1 == "NA"] <- NA
```

But I have more than 50 variables... ¿do you know a better approach? or ¿do you know what I'm doing wrong in the import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
library(memisc)
mydata <- as.data.set(spss.portable.file("myspssdata.por"))
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)
```

When the data.set is converted to data.frame all NA values are correct.

I also tried to obtain a data.frame directly:

```
mydata <- as.data.frame(spss.portable.file("myspssdata.por"))
```

But in that way I obtain a data.frame with 0 observations. So it seems that is mandatory to go through the data.set first.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
is.na(mydata) <- mydata == "NA"
```

and all `"NA"`s in all columns are replaced by actual `NA`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does not work. 'mydata' is a data.set with 62 variables. Maybe I need to convert it to something else before doing that. I don't know.

Comment: @DavidAmeller What happened when you tried this code? What was the error message?

Comment: @DavidAmeller What is the output of `any(mydata == "NA")`?

Comment: @DavidAmeller This means that none of the values in the data frame are equal to `"NA"`. Please add the output of `dput(head(mydata))` to your question.

Comment: look at this  http://pastebin.com/1Dpzh86V, when I do mydata == "NA" and when I do mydata$dc_tool == "NA". A dataframe and a dataset is the same? because when I import the data I have a "data.set".

Comment: I found the solution, it was that, just converting data.set to data.frame corrects all the NA's :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `Hmisc::spss.get` to read SPSS and NA values are imported properly:

```
library(Hmisc)
r <- spss.get(survey_results_file, use.value.labels=T)
> str(r[273,"Q5A8"])
 Factor w/ 4 levels "1 Not Important",..: NA
> is.na(r[273,"Q5A8"])
[1] TRUE
```